# jQuery - if element text matches statement, change the matched text

Tags: jquery

Below is the *idea* of what I'm trying to achieve. However I'm aware that `$(this)` doesn't work in this way, I just don't know how else to explain what i'm trying to do:

```
if($('.price').text() || $('.productPrice').text() == "£0.00"){
    $(this).text('See Product');
}
```

HTML:

`<p class="price">£0.00</p>` or `<p class="productPrice">£0.00</p>`

I would like it if the element's text matches £0.00, it changes it to "See Product". I hope this makes sense

Comment: please share your html code also. are there multiple `productPrice` elements?

Comment: Why is this -1? If you're going downvote please at least explain why. There's nothing wrong with the question :/

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting downvotes? I've explained the problem, explained that the code i posted was the idea as i didn't know how to explain it any better, posted code i had tried...

Comment: The downvote tooltip reads: "*this question does not show any research effort; is unclear or not useful*" - it was probably unclear for those who downvoted. But don't worry, if the question is good, you'll get upvotes to negate it, or if you think your question can be rephrased better, please do so, those who downvoted might undo their downvote as well...

Comment: @AndyHolmes sorry about wasting both of our time, but next time please do remember how well you explained the issue to me once we got into an argument... you could've done that before posting the question.. :D

Comment: @TJ haha it's fine. I don't doubt that i didn't explain fully in the beginning, but i did try and explain it to the best of my ability (stress and clients chasing, you know how it is haha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by passing a function into [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function):

```
$('.price, .productPrice').text(function(index, text) {
    return !text || text == "£0.00" ? "See Product" : text;
});
```

When you pass in a function, jQuery will call the function once for each element, and set the text of the element to what you return. (Note the first argument is the index, which you wouldn't use; the second is the one you want.)

Comment: I don't know why someone -1'd this, this is perfect thank you :)

Comment: It's not exactly what you asked for: "£0.00" will be replaced by "See Product" in .price as well as in .productPrice.

Comment: @MauricePerry: *"I would like it if the element's text matches £0.00, it changes it to "See Product""* immediately after *"`<p class="price">£0.00</p> or <p class="productPrice">£0.00</p>`"* seems pretty clear to me that it would should replace *either* blank or `£0.00` in *either* class of element. And indeed, apparently that's the case.

Comment: It's not that clear when you look at the piece of code that's above. I +1d your answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
$('.price, .productPrice').each( function(i, el){
  if($(this).text() === "£0.00") {  $(this).text('See Product');  }
});
```

Comment: This does work fine but i prefer the shorthand version, thank you though. I've +1'd for you